# In PyTorch, how to I make certain module `Parameters` static during training?

Tags: python, pytorch

**Context:**

In pytorch, any [`Parameter`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#parameters) is a special kind of `Tensor`. A `Parameter` is automatically registered with a module's `parameters()` method when it is assigned as an attribute.

During training, I will pass `m.parameters()` to the [`Optimizer`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#algorithms) instance so they can be updated.

---

**Question**: For a built-in pytorch module, how to I prevent certain parameters from being modified by the optimizer?

```
s = Sequential(
        nn.Linear(2,2),
        nn.Linear(2,3),   # I want this one's .weight and .bias to be constant
        nn.Linear(3,1)
    )
```

- Can I make it so they don't appear in `s.parameters()`?
- Can I make the parameters read-only so any attempted changes are ignored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters can be made static by setting their attribute `requires_grad=False`.

In my example case:

```py
params = list(s.parameters())  # .parameters() returns a generator
# Each linear layer has 2 parameters (.weight and .bias),
# Skipping first layer's parameters (indices 0, 1):
params[2].requires_grad = False
params[3].requires_grad = False
```

When a mix of `requires_grad=True` and `requires_grad=False` tensors are used to make a calculation, the result inherits `requires_grad=True`.

According to the [PyTorch autograd mechanics documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/autograd.html):

> If there’s a single input to an operation that requires gradient, its output will also require gradient. Conversely, only if all inputs don’t require gradient, the output also won’t require it. Backward computation is never performed in the subgraphs, where all Tensors didn’t require gradients.

---

My concern was that if I disabled gradient tracking for the middle layer, the first layer wouldn't receive backpropagated gradients. This was faulty understanding.

**Edge Case**: If I disable gradients for *all* parameters in a module and try to train, the optimizer will raise an exception. Because there is not a single tensor to apply the `backward()` pass to.

This edge case is why I was getting errors. I was trying to test `requires_grad=False` on parameters for module with a single `nn.Linear` layer. That meant I disabled tracking for *all* parameters, which caused the optimizer to complain.

Comment: This seems like a too hacky way to do it. Why not just exclude unwanted parameters from the list you give to the optimizer? I mean don't pass `s.parameters()` directly, create another list from it that doesn't contain unwanted parameters.

Comment: @SergeyDymchenko I want my module to be self-contained in so far as when others use it to make composite modules, they don't have to filter out a few parameters manually.